# DTerm (macOS one-stroke quick terminal) > Issues with $PATH in ZSH

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, path

I’ve been using [DTerm](https://github.com/muhqu/dterm) for a long time as a fast and convenient way to get to a “path aware” terminal prompt in macOS - but since upgrading to BigSur/ZSH, the `$PATH`  in DTerm  and Terminal.app/iTerm are very different.

I thought it was due to “migration” issues, but I'm reinstalling on a new laptop from scratch and the paths are also different:

Path in Terminal is:

```bsh
~ % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

And the path in DTerm is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I haven't (yet) customised startup files, etc. and this [appears to be an issue for the app](https://github.com/muhqu/dterm/issues/20).

Does anyone know a workaround or fix?

[image: DTerm $PATH in zsh]

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436830/dterm-one-stroke-quick-terminal-issues-with-path-in-zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** - Posting here to help others that run into this issue

The shell that DTerm uses is an *interactive* but not *login* shell (see at the bottom how to check what type of shell you have)

That means DTerm *does not* execute `/etc/zprofile` on startup, and that is where the path is "updated" in macOS:

```
# Setup user specific overrides for this in ~/.zprofile. See zshbuiltins(1)
# and zshoptions(1) for more details.

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

Copying this mechanism to .zshrc fixes the issue. To potentially avoiding messing up the `$PATH`, I've used this form:

```
if ([ $TERM_PROGRAM = DTerm ]); then 
    if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
    fi
fi
```

##### Check the type of shell:

The simplest way I've found to check if the shell is login or not (since it reads keyboard it's interactive), is to use `echo $0`:

| Terminal | DTerm |
| --- | --- |
| `~ % echo $0` `-zsh` | `~ % echo $0` `/bin/zsh` |

Login shells have a -dash in front of the name. To get all options of the shell, there is `echo $-` - login shells have `l` and interactive have `i`

| Terminal | DTerm |
| --- | --- |
| `~ % echo $-` `569XZilms` | `~ % echo $0` `569XZi` |

Or a more "explicit" way is to use:

`[[ -o interactive ]] && echo "Interactive" || echo "Non-Interactive"`

and

`[[ -o login ]] && echo "Login" || echo "Non-Login"`

which will output whether the shell is Interactive or Login shell

Sources:

- [linux - What is the difference between a 'Login' and an 'Interactive' bash shell - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/8882/what-is-the-difference-between-a-login-and-an-interactive-bash-shell)
- [How to check if a shell is login/interactive/batch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600541/8665)
- [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html#l7)